# How to slove (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/core' in Visual Studio2019

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I create Asp.Net Core Project with Angular template.
each import row with '@angular/...'; has an error

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Comment: What error? What configuration? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run "npm install"?  If not, you need to run "npm install" from the root folder.